# How to send mail with asp.net in vb.net

Tags: send

When I send an email
By pressing the button
No error will not be

```
Dim mm As MailMessage = New MailMessage("ashkanramedani1370@gmail.com", "ashkanramedani1370@gmail.com", "HELLO", "test")
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("gmail.com")
    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    Dim NetworkCred As NetworkCredential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential()
    NetworkCred.UserName = "ashkanramedani1370@gmail.com"
    NetworkCred.Password = "123456789@"
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred
    smtp.Port = 587
    Try
        smtp.Send(mm)
    Catch ex As Exception
        '----
    End Try
```

But did not receive the email
Please help me

Comment: Remove your `Catch` block and find out what the exception is.

Answer (score 0):

`gmail.com` is not an SMTP server.

You want `smtp.gmail.com`.

Comment: Yes ,
I changed . But I still have not received any email